# Controling Partial view from controller based on condition in Razor MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my home view I have below HTMl with 3 partial views. In that First Partial view will render always. Second and Third will be decided by home controller based on Flag 0 or 1. 
How to handle such situation. Please suggest me.

```
<div>             
    <div>
        -- some HTML
    </div>   
    @{ Html.RenderAction("First", "First");}
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Second", "Second");}
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Third", "Third");}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the issue if you decide you flag in your controller as you are saying and then sent it to view and then simply use this flag in the view to decide whether or not to render second and third?

In Controller

```
ViewBag.Flag = bool // 0 or 1 as per your logic
```

In View

```
if(ViewBag.Flag){
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Second", "Second");}
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Third", "Third");}
}
```

Comment: how did you concluded this? It will not render and how it could when it's not executing the statements inside the if statement if flag is 0?

Comment: No your understanding of the workflow is completely wrong.  Partial actions are executed before sending the output to client. When compiling the Razor View if Razor Engine come across the RenderActoin Statement (which it will not when Flag is 0) a full different request life cycle of MVC starts. Then the output of this new MVC request is placed at the same place from where partial request started.

Comment: I am not that good of a teacher. May be someone else could help you out here. But you can verify this by putting some kind of logging function in your partial actions and then check if they get executed or not :)

Comment: So what's the conclusion, Did you got what you were looking for?